# How do I push items into an array in the data object in Vuejs? Vue seems not to be watching the .push() method

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I am attempting to add objects into an array I declared in Vue instance data object. I can set the values in the state's purchase object, but when I push data into the orders queue array, the empty array is not populated. The function is being triggered, but the array does not update.

Here is my form:

```
<form
  v-on:submit.prevent="queuePurchase"
  class="form-inline row"
  id="order-creation-form"
  method="POST"
>

  @csrf
  <autocomplete-field
    sizing="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3"
    name="customer"
    label="Customer"
    :data="{{ json_encode($customers) }}"
    v-on:setcustomer="setCustomer($event)"
  ></autocomplete-field>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md3 form-group d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
    <label for="phone">Product</label>
    <select
      v-model="purchase.product"
      class="form-control w-100"
      name="product"
      aria-describedby="productHelpBlock"
      required
    >
      @foreach ($products as $product)
        <option :value="{{ json_encode($product) }}">
          {{ $product->name }}
        </option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
    <small id="productHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
      Select a product
    </small>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 form-group d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
    <label for="phone">Quantity</label>
    <input
      v-model="purchase.quantity"
      type="number"
      min="1"
      name="product"
      class="form-control w-100"
      aria-describedby="productHelpBlock"
      required
    >
    <small id="productHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
      Product quantity
    </small>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success icon-button d-flex">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;  Q U E U E</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
require("./bootstrap");
window.Vue = require("vue");

Vue.component("queue-table", require('./components/QueueTable.vue'));
Vue.component("autocomplete-field", require('./components/AutocompleteField.vue'));

const purchaseApp = new Vue({
    el: "#purchase-app",

    data() {
        return {
            queue: [],
            purchase: {
                product: null,
                customer: null,
                quantity: null
            }
        }
    },

    methods: {
        setCustomer: function(customerObj) {
            this.purchase.customer = customerObj;
        },

        queuePurchase: function() {
            this.queue.push( this.purchase );
        }
    }
});
```

Could someone please explain what  & why it is happening?

Comment: you can read about reactivity in vue here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Comment: @ChrisLi .push() should be covered according to this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods

Comment: This should work. You probably want to copy the `purchase` objects though before you push them to `queue`. Objects are [reference types](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0). So your queue will always store the same reference (which points to `this.purchase`).

Comment: where do you display the queue ?

Comment: you had set `:data="{{ json_encode($customers) }}"` i think you can't do that, probably you can do `:customers="{{ json_encode($customers) }}"` and in your data object set ` data() {
        return { customers :[] ...`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `push()` method ought to add `purchase` objects to the `queue` array, but as @FK82 pointed out in his comment, `push()` is adding multiple references to the same `purchase` object. This means that if you change the object by increasing the `quantity`, every `purchase`'s `quantity` property will be updated.

You can give that a try here:

```js
const exampleComponent = Vue.component("example-component", {
  name: "exampleComponent",
  template: "#example-component",
  data() {
    return {
      queue: [],
      purchase: {
        product: null,
        customer: null,
        quantity: null
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    queuePurchase() {
      this.queue.push( this.purchase );
    }
  }
});

const page = new Vue({
  name: "page",
  el: ".page",
  components: {
    "example-component": exampleComponent
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="example-component">
  <div>
    <p>The Queue has {{ this.queue.length }} items.</p>
    <input
      v-model="purchase.quantity"
      type="number"
      min="1"
      name="product"
      placeholder="Quantity"
    >
    <button @click="queuePurchase">
      Add to Queue
    </button>
    <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(this.queue, null, 2) }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<div class="page">
  <example-component></example-component>
</div>
```

Instead of `push()`ing a reference to the same `purchase` object, try creating a shallow copy with `Object.assign({}, this.purchase)` or by using the spread operator. Here's an example that uses the spread operator and then `push()`es the copy onto the `queue`:

```js
const exampleComponent = Vue.component("example-component", {
  name: "exampleComponent",
  template: "#example-component",
  data() {
    return {
      queue: [],
      purchase: {
        product: null,
        customer: null,
        quantity: null
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    queuePurchase() {
      this.queue.push({...this.purchase});
    }
  }
});

const page = new Vue({
  name: "page",
  el: ".page",
  components: {
    "example-component": exampleComponent
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="example-component">
  <div>
    <p>The Queue has {{ this.queue.length }} items.</p>
    <input
      v-model="purchase.quantity"
      type="number"
      min="1"
      name="product"
      placeholder="Quantity"
    >
    <button @click="queuePurchase">
      Add to Queue
    </button>
    <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(this.queue, null, 2) }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<div class="page">
  <example-component></example-component>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried above way to avoid reactivity but It does not work on props data why?